# Style unstyled links with DOM and xpath

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

For a system I am building I am defining a general `style` stored in `LINKSTYLE` that should be applied to `a` elements that are not yet styled (inline). I am not very experienced with the `DOMDocument` or `xpath` and I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Thanks to Gordon I've updated my code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);    

$html  = '<a href="#">test</a>'.
         '<a href="#" style="border:1px solid #000;">test2</a>';

$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$dom->normalizeDocument();  
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//a[not(@style)]') as $node)
    $node->setAttribute('style','border:1px solid #000');

return $html;
```

With this **updated** code I receive no more errors, however the `a` element does not get styled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` to suppress parsing errors stemming from `loadHTML`.

- [`libxml_use_internal_errors()` — Disable libxml errors and allow user to fetch error information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

The XPath query is invalid because `contains` expects a value to search for in the style attribute.

- [`fn:contains($arg1 as xs:string?, $arg2 as xs:string?) as xs:boolean`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains)

If you want to find all anchors without a style element, just use

```
//a[not(@style)]
```

You are not seeing your changes, because you are returning the string stored in $html. Once you loaded the string with DOMDocument, you have to serialize it back after you have have run your query and modified the DOMDocument's internal representation of that string.

**Example ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/G7dkNM))**

```
$html = <<< HTML
<ul>
    <li><a href="#foo" style="font-weight:bold">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bar">bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#baz">baz</a></li>
</ul>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query('//a[not(@style)]') as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0));
```

**Output:**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#foo" style="font-weight:bold">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bar" style="font-weight:bold">bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#baz" style="font-weight:bold">baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that in order to use [`saveHTML` with an argument, you need at least PHP 5.3.6.](http://gooh.posterous.com/the-dom-goodie-in-php-536)

Comment: Hey, the parsing errors then probably are from not 100% valid HTML? Now when I change the xpath to what you said I don't get an error anymore but the `a` elements are not styled. I've added a testcase to my question.

Comment: Wow that looks obvious, I didn't think about the fact that the HTML was being handled internally and had to be reassigned to the `$html` variable. It works when I'm using `saveHTML()` without an argument, but I would like to know why you are using it? It seems to me like you are only saving the first tag which is `<a href="#foo" style="font-weight:bold">foo</a>`. But why would you not save the entire document? And why would you save only this tag, especially since it's the only already styled one. Thanks for the help either way!

Comment: @Kokos The DOM extension uses libxml underneath. When you use `loadHTML` libxml will use its HTML parser module which can read broken HTML. But to achieve that, the parser module will add implied elements, which means when you only do `saveHTML`, you will have a DocType and a html and body tag added. If you are operating on a full HTML document, that isnt an issue, because those elements will be there anyways (so nothing added). Your example only shows a partial document and then it matters, because you wouldnt get that partial back but a full document, e.g. with implied elements.

Comment: Luckily the actual system is operating on a full HTML document. Thanks mate!

Comment: Hey Gordon, I have one more question. I am now having charset problems, my HTML input contains `<meta charset="utf-8">` and at first I fixed my problems by using `utf8_encode()` on all the text. But now after doing this `DOMDocument` process characters such as `Ã¯` are appearing again. Do you know what is causing / what will fix this?

Comment: @Kokos: If the charset is already UTF-8 of the document, just don't `utf8_encode()` it again. DomDocument works with UTF-8 by default. Input strings should be UTF-8 and output strings are UTF-8.

Comment: @Hakre, this was the first thing I thought. I removed the `utf8_encode()` on my database data. But still the output is encoded wrongly. I think my error is somewhere else, I can't post the full code here nor my real urls for various reasons so I'll just look around myself.

Comment: @Kokos try with `$dom->encoding = 'utf-8'`. If that doesnt help, put the `utf8_encode` calls back in. If that doesnt help try with `iconv`. Also check your server headers. Meta elements are fallback elements. If your server sends an encoding header, the Meta is never picked up.

Comment: Hm, I actually just didn't remove `utf8_encode()` in all places, I forgot some >_>. Thanks guys, and @Gordon I will keep those in mind if I run into encoding troubles again.

Comment: I'm playing a bit with doing this more on the CSS part, will add it as an answer when done.

Answer (score 1):

The first error (before editing) occurs when you use inside document a `&` for other purposes than creating a entity-reference (e.g. `&quot;`).

Usually this happens in URLs when you delimit GET-parameters.

You can ignore this errors using Gordon's suggestion or fix it(replace occurences of `&` by `&amp;`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this actually happens because I am using the `&` character to define fields that get replaced with database information like so: `&&&&field&&&&`. Luckily these errors can just be surpressed :)

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if it's possible to solve this more CCS-wise, e.g. with a selector. In CSS3 it's possible to only address those `<a>` tags that don't have the `style` attribute:

```
a:not([style]) {border:1px solid #000;}
```

So if your documents already have a stylesheet it could be easily added.

If not, then a `<style>` must be added to the document. This can be done with DomDocument as well but I found it a bit complicated. However I got it to work for some little play:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);    

$html  = '<a href="#">test</a>'.
         '<a href="#" style="border:1px solid #000;">test2</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$dom->normalizeDocument();

// ensure that there is a head element, body will always be there
// because of loadHtml();
$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head');
if (0 == $head->length) {
    $head = $dom->createElement('head');
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $head = $body->parentNode->insertBefore($head, $body);
} else {
    $head=$head->item(0);
}

// append style tag to head.
$css = 'a:not([style]) {border:1px solid #000;}';
$style = $dom->createElement('style');
$style->nodeValue=$css;
$head->appendChild($style);

$dom->formatOutput = true;
$output = $dom->saveHtml();

echo $output;
```

Example output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><style>a:not([style]) {border:1px solid #000;}</style></head>
<body>
<a href="#">test</a><a href="#" style="border:1px solid #000;">test2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If the CSS clashes with other, higher selectors, this is not an easy solution. `!important` might help though.

#### HTML Fragment

And as far of getting the changed HTML fragment, this is some additional code that can work with gordons suggestion. Just the inner-html of the body tag, this time I played a bit with the SPL:

```
// get html fragment
$output = implode('', array_map(
  function($node) use ($dom) { return $dom->saveXml($node); },
  iterator_to_array($xpath->query('//body/*'), false)))
  ;
```

A foreach is definitely more readable and memory friendly:

```
// get html fragment
$output = '';
foreach($xpath->query('//body/*') as $node) 
  $output .= $dom->saveXml($node)
  ;
```

Comment: Hey Hakre, +1 for your thought process but this will not work for me since the system is part of a e-mail marketing system. For that reason I am unable to use stylesheets and this is also the reason I have to check for inline style tags and the sorts.

Comment: Ah okay, sure, then you need to hardencode styles mad-hatter-style. Wrench those html chunks and blast those broken html-email-clients ;)

Comment: nice. But keep in mind that when you are using `saveXml` you will get XML compliant output, e.g. '<br/>' instead of `<br>`. While I wholeheartily agree that all HTML is tag soup anyway, the difference should be pointed out.

Comment: Yeah right. Especially as this is about the fragment which is for HTML. I should check if `saveHTML()` can cure that.