# How to parse these strings

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I am having a few problems with cleaning up XPaths results (php/domxpath). Usually I would try to achieve this with Regex, but I noticed a lot of anti-regex suggestions around here, so I wanted to ask if there are any better solutions to my problems.

#### Separating City and Zip Code

Xpath delivers "10021 New York City". Zip and City vary. How would I best split these?

#### Extracting Infos from an Url

Xpath delivers "http://www.whatever.com/?k=5000+z=6000". How would I best extract the "k=500+z=600"?

#### Extracting Infos from a longer text segment

Xpath delivers "total size might be 3130ft² or more". Only consistent pattern is number followed by ft².

Comment: It appears your question has nothing to do with XPath.  You just need to parse text...right?

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes :) I came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423079/style-unstyled-links-with-dom-and-xpath/6423206 and thought XPath was a viable solution for that.

Comment: FYI: I edited your post to reflect your intent.

Comment: which language are you using? php? Please tag your questions with the language

Comment: @Bohemian yes, updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
if (preg_match('/(\d+) (.*)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $zip = $regs[1];
    $city = $regs[2];
}
```

2.

```
if (preg_match('/[^?]*$/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $size= $regs[0];
}
```

(although you should use a URL parser for that, actually)

3.

```
if (preg_match('/\d+(?=ft²)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak php, but here's an attempt:

City/zip:

```
zip = preg_replace ( '/.*(\d+).*/', '$1' , zipAndCity)
city = preg_replace ( '/\d+/', '' , zipAndCity)
```

url params:

```
params = preg_replace ( '/.*\?/', '' , url)
```

area:

```
area = preg_replace ( '/.*(\d+ft.*?(?= ))/', '$1' , areaDesc)
```

If someone spots a syntax error, please edit. Thanks.